# I am having difficulty understanding why the string index is out of range

Tags: python

The program I am trying to make checks for reiterances of letter in the given word, however, when the word has multiples of the same letter, for instance 'hello' has multiple 'l', the program prints an error saying that the string index is out of range, and I am curious as to why that is.
I have looked at the other threads, but i am still curious as to why that is.
The bottom for loop is where the issue is located.

```
right =""
guess=""
attempts = 6
tries = 0

print("Hangman: guess letters until you can guess the word or phrase.")
print("In this game you get six tries.")

right_str = str(input("\nEnter your word: "))

#checks to see if user input is all letters or if there are none letters in the string
while right_str.isalpha()==False:
    print("Error, only letters are accepted as an input")
    right_str = str(input("Enter your word: "))

#displays the proper amount of unknown spaces
for i in range(0, len(right_str)):
    right += "-"


print("current: " + right)
print("0 guesses so far out of 6: " + guess)

for i in range(0, 6):
    guessed = str(input("Letter guessed: "))

    if guessed.lower() in right_str.lower():
        for i in range(0, len(right_str)):
            if right_str[i] in guessed:
                right = right[:i] + guessed[i] + right[i + 1:]
                print(right)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re the code segment:

```
if guessed.lower() in right_str.lower():
    for i in range(0, len(right_str)):
        if right_str[i] in guessed:
            right = right[:i] + guessed[i] + right[i + 1:]
            print(right)
```

If `guessed` is a single letter, what do you expect will happen in your loop when you use `guessed[i]`? Bottom line, you should be using `guessed` on its own, not attempting to index it.

---

By the way, while your attempts to handle varying case in your input is commendable, you've left at least *one* small hole in it with the third line above (not using `guessed.lower()`).

You'll probably find it's better to convert everything to lower (or upper) case as it's entered, and store it consistently. That way, comparisons will automatically be correct.

---

And, one final note, your `print` statement which outputs the updated `right` string is happening *within* the loop meaning that a word like `hello` or `Mississippi` is going to result in a lot of outputs for certain guesses.

If your intent is to print out the new result after *all* occurrences of the current letter have been added, simply move the `print` to outside the loop, something like (with the added changes suggested in the previous section as well):

```
right_str = str(input("\nEnter your word: ")).lower()
:
guessed = str(input("Letter guessed: ")).lower()
:
if guessed in right_str:
    for i in range(0, len(right_str)):
        if right_str[i] in guessed:
            right = right[:i] + guessed + right[i + 1:]
    print(right)
```

---

And, of course, there's almost *always* a more Pythonic way to do this:

```
right = "".join([right_str[i] if right_str[i] == guessed else right[i] for i in range(len(right_str))])
```

I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader to figure out how it works. Once you grok that, you can probably consider yourself a true Pythonista :-)

Comment: Does that mean it will only replace the first appearance/index of the letter?

Comment: It means that you can't index into a character beyond index 0, so most of the time you'll go out-of-bounds.

Comment: so, i should just delete that?

Comment: @user7433120, sorry, I may have been a bit obtuse in that I asked what you thought would happen but didn't actually provided a definitive solution. Fixed that now. As per your "first occurrence" question, no, it will replace every occurrence within `right` because of the `for .. range` loop.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! Your solution worked, however, i seem to get 2 printouts. The first being --l--, and the second being --ll-. Is there any way to ignore the first? Loop maybe?

Comment: Appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! That helped me get started on the next bit that i need to do

Comment: This is an attempt at making hangman, and i forgot that i needed to do phrases as well. Any tips on how to go about that. *not looking for a direct solution at the moment

Comment: @user7433120, phrases are no different to words other than the fact you need to allow for spaces (and possibly other "punctuation") - allowing them in the string but not allowing them as guesses, meaning that your user-visible string will need to start as something like `-- ---------- -- ---- -- ----`.

Comment: My bad! i stated the wrong thing. When i went to type in hello directly as the solution, the output was odd. hhhhhellollollollollo----. I need to figure out how to add words as potential solution

Comment: @user7433120, you'd be better off posting your new code into *another* question since it's basically a different issue.

Comment: Give me time to write it and then i will

Answer (score -1):

I think your problem is here: right[i + 1:]
If you are in the last element, it'll give the index out of range error.

Comment: im still getting index out of range. it has no issue when dealing with single characters to replace, it only has an issue when there are multiple instances of that character

Comment: Another problem seems to be the first and second for use I as index car. Can you change the first to j, for example?

Comment: By first and second I mean the nested for.

Comment: Also, guessed on that concatenation seems odd. I think it should be just guessed.

Comment: I think you'll find that, while `"hello"[9999]` will indeed generate an error, `"hello"[9999:]` (with the colon) works fine, giving you an empty string.